# Distribution of digit-groups in random numbers

Tags: probability, distributions, algorithms

I'm storing files and giving them random numbers as the name, using a 32 bit unsigned range, and writing it as hex. Eg: `087b8a08`.

To avoid having too many files in any one directory I split the name like: `08/7b/8a/08`.

I've noticed that at the top level I have a reasonable number of file names, but each level down that I go there are fewer and fewer files in each directory. (Since I obviously don't store every possible name, just a small subset, eg 10,000, or a 1 million, out of a possible 4 billion.)

What's a good strategy to divide up the hex-digits to have approximately the same number of names at each level, given: an expected number of files that I store, and how many level to divide into?

I read that dividing by e (rounded to 3) each time minimizes the number of items in a level vs the number of levels. But I think that doesn't apply here since I don't use every number name.

Comment: Why on earth would you name files like this? Most programming languages have build in functions to uniquely assign file names without the risk of random duplication, however small.  Why is there a concern of having too many names in a directory?  Have you given any thought to writing your files to a database, as they are particularly well suited for tasks like this?

Comment: @Stats In many operating systems, having large numbers of files in a directory degrades file searches and thus impairs all operations requiring access to files.  Having more than ten or so files per directory slows down human navigation considerably.  Although the database idea is a good one, if those files need to be available directly to other software it might not be an option.

Comment: Well certainly I can appreciate the issue of possible degradation of performance.  There are many of programs written to do do exactly what the OP is asking without having to rely on possibly dupblicating file names. I'd recommend the OP check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197162/ntfs-performance-and-large-volumes-of-files-and-directories and consider posting there.  I view this more as a computer/program issue, rather than a statistical one, really.

Comment: I also mean to include:  http://serverfault.com/questions/98235/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many-downloading-data-from-net

Comment: @StatsStudent A database is bad because it is MUCH slower to backup. Each file is permanent, so once it is backed up future incremental backups never need touch it again. In a database you backup the entire data store each time. And you should know that in general a database does a very bad job of storing files, databases are not designed for that. File system are.

Comment: @StatsStudent I don't need programming help, I don't need help on dealing with duplicate file names, I know very well the performance characteristics on the filesystems I use. I only put that in there for some background. I was simply asking about the statistics on how the random numbers work out. If you could post an answer about that I would appreciate it.

Comment: @whuber Many directory levels also slows down the computer, not just the human. It's a balancing act between how many files (which slows it down if too many) and how many directory levels (which also slows it down). I was hoping to get some numbers on various scenarios so I can pick something based on my knowledge of how to balance the two.

Comment: @Ariel, I don't necessarily agree with your comments regarding the database, but I'll assume you know what is best for your particular situation. That being said, maybe I'm just not understanding what you are trying to do, but it seems like maybe you are making things too hard for yourself. Rather than using hex digits, why not simply use sequential integers, and write, say the first n, files to director_n, the next n files to directory_n*2? If you are simply interested in properties of random digits, I think you can make the question a more clear by removing the superfluous background info.

Answer (score 0):

You have 32 bits, and assuming you have a uniform distribution, the expected size is halved with every bit that you use.
It's straightforward to estimate the number of files at each level. But I suggest you don't overthink this. Use either `ab/abcdef01` (reduce by 256) or `ab/cd/abcdef01` (reduce by 256^2) because you probably won't get as much benefit from any further nesting as you expect. At some point the actual number of files and data is the problem, not only in one directory.

E.g. the well-known squid proxy cache uses 16*256 folders (so probably `a/bc/`. I doubt it uses random numbers (that would be rather useless) but most likely it uses a hash code of the web host name.